# Remove space between two references

Tags: natbib, multiple-citations

I'm using `elsarticle` document class with biboptions for references. When I cite two references there is a space between them [1, 2]. I'd like to have a citation like [1,2], but I don't know how to remove the space.

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{natbib}
\biboptions[square,numbers,sort&compress]

\begin{document}

\section*{Introduction}
Palm oil is mainly composed of triglycerides \cite{Mba2015,Kamboh2015}.

\bibliography{SFC}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is this for a paper you're intending to submit to an Elsevier journal? If so, you shouldn't care about it, the text will be re-typeset by Elsevier anyway.

Comment: It's for a paper I'll submit to an Elsevier journal.

Comment: In that case I'd recommend not to bother with tweaking the layout of the references. Just follow the documentation and avoid adding long preamble code that changes minute details in the output. Elsevier will probably process your submission with non-TeX tools anyway and small modifications like this may well fall through the cracks and will be lost.

Comment: Thank you @moewe.